# Approximation of real numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there any function $f(x)$, such that for all real $\alpha$ and rational $p/q$
$$\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{1}{f(q)}.$$
or at least
$$\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq\frac{1}{f(q)}$$
have finitely many solutions in $(p,q)$ for all real $\alpha$.

Comment: wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

Comment: Hint: the set of $\alpha$ such that $0<|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{c}{f(q)}$ for some $p/q$ is open dense. Now apply Baire's theorem to intersect on all $c$.

Comment: I understand, that such a function $f(x)$ is not a polynomial, because of Liouville numbers.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Ah yes. Perhaps this then: the set of $\alpha$ such that $0<|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{f(q)}$ for some $p/q$ irreducible with $q\geq q_0$ is open dense. Now apply Baire's theorem to intersect on all $q_0$.

Comment: Sure. Let $f(q)<0$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: the conclusion is that given $f$, there exists a dense $G_\delta$ of $\alpha$ for which the inequality has infinitely many solutions, therefore the answer to the question is no.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar My point was to explain why for every $f$ (positive, of course), there exists $\alpha$ such that $0<|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{f(q)}$ has infinitely many solutions (so the answer to OP's second question would be "no").

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hurt to make $f(x)$ bigger, so one may assume that $f(x+1) \ge 2 \cdot f(x)$. Let $\alpha_0 = 1$, let $\alpha_n = p_n/q_n$ in smallest terms, and let

$$\alpha_{n+1} = \alpha_{n} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot f(q_n)}.$$

Then $\alpha = \lim \alpha_n$  satsifies

$$\left| \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| = \left| \alpha - \alpha_n \right|
=  \frac{1}{2 f(q_n)}  + \frac{1}{2 f(q_{n+1})} + \ldots  \le \frac{1}{2 f(q_n)} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots \right) \le \frac{1}{f(q_n)}.$$